# Failed Opening required error. required once

Tags: php, apache

I am getting the following error from my website in the error logs:

```
[Wed Jul 02 07:13:58 2014] [error] [client **.**.**.**] 
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/var/zpanel/hostdata/
zadmin/core/public_html/loader.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')
in /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/cmcatering_co_uk/index.php on line 3
```

In index.php I have the following:

```
<?php
$code_base = "/var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/core";
require_once($code_base . "/public_html/loader.php");
?>
```

The loader.php file is in the correct place and so I am a bit confused as to why this is happening. I tried putting the core folder in /usr/share/php but this did not fix the problem. Any suggestions?

edit:

I have also just seen this error:

> [Wed Jul 02 07:36:58 2014] [error] [client 94.10.110.115] PHP Warning:  require_once(/usr/share/php/core/public_html/loader.php): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted in /var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/cmcatering_co_uk/index.php on line 3

httpd.conf:

```
# ZPanel Apache Include file for CentOS Linux
# Written by Bobby Allen, 15/05/2011

# Set the Zpanel Alias (used for development, sable will eventually use a VHOST)
Alias /zpanel /etc/zpanel/panel

# Setup the directory settings and PHP security flags for the Zpanel application      directory.
<Directory /etc/zpanel/panel>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
        php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
         php_flag track_vars On
    php_flag register_globals Off
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /etc/zpanel/temp
</IfModule>

</Directory>  

# Disallow web access to directories that don't need it/that we don't want people looking in!
<Directory /etc/zpanel/panel/cnf>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Directory>

# Set server tokens (security??)
ServerTokens Maj

# Now we include the generic VHOST configuration file that holds all the ZPanel user hosted vhost data
Include /etc/zpanel/configs/apache/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you read the error message then you well see:

```
Operation not permitted
```

Your webserver process has no permissions to access

```
/usr/share/php/core/public_html/
```

In many cases webservers are bound to their root.

```
/var/zpanel/hostdata/
```

Comment: How could I give permission to the share folder or change the include path to be in the hostdata folder?

Comment: This is really depending on your server configuration. In php there is an restriction if open_basedir is set. Suhosin can also restrict access. I think it's more related to the webserver worker process. that account seems to be restricted and has no access to /var.

Comment: Thank you. I will see if anyone on the zpanel forums has encounted this sort of thing before.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though this is a permissions issue due to the operation not permitted error. Look at whether your server is giving php access to the given folder in its configuration. Also just for a sanity check, echo out the filename as it is passed to your require_once.

Would be helpful if you posted your apache site config.

Comment: I have added apache config now. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

```
        <?php
        $code_base = "/var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/core";
        require_once("<?php echo $code_base; ?>/public_html/loader.php");
        ?>
```

Comment: Why do you suggest this code? Please add some details to this and further answers. (Your answer was flagged as low quality) Additionally it's just wrong and can't work.